# Firefox cannot download certain files when set to ask where to save files

Tags: linux, firefox, download

This does not happen with all files, just with some downloads that seem to have nothing special, like from launchpad or deviantart. The same files are downloaded if the setting is changed to download the files without asking.

[image]

Practically the option to ask where to download is unusable now.

What to do?

---

Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon

Firefox 33.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching `firefox -p`, I have created a brand new user profile and in this way the problem disappeared.

I imagined that the problem is related to my large user configuration directory, which is a very old backup containing all addons etc, even from Windows. That was the probable cause but at the same time I do not want to lose those configurations, so I can check them in the old profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the "Reset download actions for all file types" option to default by just following the steps:

Click the Menu icon > Help button (?)> choose "Troubleshooting Information" > click on "Show Folder" > Now, change the file name of mimeTypes.rdf and restart the Firefox. Now check the file download.

Hope this helps.

Comment: after doing that it asks me where to save but then nothing happens. think back I am using Nemo as file manager but when also installing Nautilus Firefox started using it (clicking for the folder of the finished downloads opened Nautilus). The problem was present before and after removing Nautilus. I do not know if it was present before installing it.